# how can I add specific controls on each of my tab?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-imagebutton

here's my second activity which holds the general codes

```
package com.go.experimentfive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class SecondActivity extends TabActivity {
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        mTabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        // Greek Tab
        intent = new Intent(this, GreekActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Greek")
                .setIndicator("Greek")
                .setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Norse tab
        intent = new Intent(this, NorseActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Norse")
                .setIndicator("Norse")
                .setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Roman Tab
        intent = new Intent(this, RomanActivity.class);
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Roman")
                .setIndicator("Roman")
                .setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My tabs (Norse)

```
package com.go.experimentfive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NorseActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Norse Mythology");
        setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

(Roman)

```
package com.go.experimentfive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RomanActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Roman Mythology");
        setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

(Greek)

```
package com.go.experimentfive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GreekActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Greek Mythology");
        setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

what do you suggest I should do? I want to insert a large amount of words on each tabs and an image button. Thanks for helping

Comment: `TabActivity`, and having activities as the contents of tabs, has been deprecated as a technique **for over four years**. Please use a more modern tab solution, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, or `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: which one should I modify?